# How to drop-while in python?

Tags: python

I've got a list of numbers, e.g.:

```
l=[0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

What I want to know is, how many leading values do I need to drop to get a list of all zeros?

So the answer here is `4`.

I'm thinking, reverse the list, then use a for loop and a counter to run down the list until I find the first non-zero element, and then subtract counter and list length, but it seems a bit ugly.

Is there a nice 'pythonic' way to do it?

(Edit for clarity:

```
l=[0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

should go to `11`, so I can't just use filter. I want to know how long the producer took to settle down to the point where the output becomes continuously zero)

Comment: will it always be the case that the 0s will be cluttered in the end?

Comment: So your final result is supposed to output a number of how many you need to remove in order for the list to be full of zeroes? Is your list always going to be ordered that way? Are there going to be cases where there are non-zeroes between the zeroes?

Comment: `sum(1 for x in l if x !=0)`?

Comment: What if your list is `[1,1,0,0,0,..,0,1]`?

Comment: Will the list possibly be very long? I can think of concise, pythonic ways to do your job that are quadratic in run-time complexity, which does not matter for lists as small as your example. The best ways are linear, of course.

Comment: can zero exist between non zero?

Comment: edited for clarity, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.dropwhile` and `itertools.takewhile` for this:

```
>>> l = [0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x != 0, l))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 0, l))
[0.01, 0.02, 0.01, -0.01]
>>> sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 0, l))
4
```

However, if you want the list to contain only `0`, then dropping from the front might not work if there are zeros and then non-zero elements again. Instead, you might better start from the end, using `reversed`, until you find the first non-zero element.

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x == 0, reversed(l)))
10
>>> sum(1 for _ in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, reversed(l)))
4
```

Here, the first is the number of consecutive zeros starting from the end of the list, and the second the number of the remaining elements starting with the first non-zero, again from the end.

Comment: len(list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, reversed(l))))?

Comment: itertools.dropwhile is totally the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden Note that using `len(list(...))` you first have to materialize the entire list, while `sum` will just compute the length by summing `1` for each element, without creating the filtered list. If the list is large, this might be preferable.

Comment: Alternatively go by index: `next(dropwhile(lambda i: l[i] == 0, reversed(range(len(l)))))+1`

Answer (score 3):

```
point = next(index for index, value in enumerate(reversed(l)) if value != 0)

point = len(l) - point if point else -1
```

We iterate over the list in reversed order till we get the first non 0 element. We use that index and subtract it from length to get the actual point.

updated code as suggest in comment.

Thanks tobias_k

Comment: Neat, but you don't have to generate the entire list, just `next((index for index, value in enumerate(reversed(l)) if value != 0), None)`. Also, the check should probably be `!= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a particularly Pythonic and efficient way to do this. You could iterate backwards over the list using `range`, but I think it's slightly cleaner to use the `reversed` list iterator:

```
def nonzeros(seq):
    for i, v in enumerate(reversed(seq)):
        if v:
            break
    return len(seq) - i

lst = [0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
print(nonzeros(lst))
lst = [0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
print(nonzeros(lst))
```

**output**

```
4
11
```

Answer (score 1):

`pop` would make your counting easy:

```
l=[0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
while not l.pop():
    pass
result = len(l) + 1
assert result == 4
```

**Edit**

I would make it a function though:

```
def foo(original):
    clone = original[:]
    while not clone.pop(): pass
    return len(clone) + 1

l=[0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
assert foo(l) == 4

l=[0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
assert foo(l) == 11
```

Comment: What do you mean? It works for me in both 2.7.10 and 3.6.1

Comment: This is a bit expensive, as you destroy the original list *and* have to create a new list of zeroes.

Comment: `clone = original.copy()` and `while clone.pop() == 0:` both may be more readable, explicit. @chepner the list does have to be copied and then is shortened from the end (cheap), but there's no *'new list of zeroes'*

Answer (score 1):

Reversing the list is an O(n) operation anyway, so there's no point. Just walk the list and note the index of the last non-zero element.

```
last = -1
for i, value in enumerate(l):
    if value != 0:
        last = i
```

(Consider using a tolerance test instead of strict equality for `value`.)

After the walk, `last + 1` is the index of the first 0 in the longest all-zero suffix of your list. That is, `all(x == 0 for x in l[last+1:])` will be true.

Comment: @kindall Oops. Thanks.

Comment: `reversed` returns a generator that allows you to iterate through the list backwards, not a new list that's reversed. so not `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
for i,j in enumerate(reversed(l)) :
    if j:
        print (len(l[:-i]))
        break
```

Output:

```
11
```

Comment: Used `reversed` rather than a slice. `l[::-1]` will make an unnecessary copy of the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

How about a verbatim solution, e.g. find the maximal index of a non-zero element?

```
res = max(i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x != 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The length of the list is stored with its internal data.  Start with the length of the full list, and then iterate through the list backwards until you find a non-zero value.

Worst case complexity should be O(n) if the list is all zeros.

It would be lightning fast in the case of a very long list with only a couple of zeros at the end before the first non-zero value, such as `my_list = [5] * 1000000 + [0, 0]`.

```
my_list = [0.01, 0.02, 0.01, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
n = len(my_list)
while n:
    n -= 1
    if my_list[n] != 0:
        n += 1
        break
>>> n
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> l=[0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on a reversed iterator of the list to group the value of the last item for as long as that value is `==` the value before it:

```
>>> last_grp=next((k, len(l)-sum(1 for _ in v)) for k,v in groupby(reversed(l)))
>>> last_grp
(0, 11)
```

The first element of the tuple returned will be the repeated value of the last group -- `0` in this case. The length of that group then is how long. Subtract that from the overall list length for the index to the start of the group.

[reversed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) and groupby are iterators. [next](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) returns the next value of an iterator. Since this is the last group, it is only needed once. This is efficient on any size list.

This works on a group of anything where `l[x-1]==l[x]` and the value of `k` is set to whatever value that is. `groupby` does just that -- groups items of the same value together.

You could also use `groupby` to find ranges where some condition is `True` or `False`; in this case, created than `0`:

```
di={True:[], False:[]}
for k, v in groupby(enumerate(l), key=lambda t: t[1]>0):
    grp=list(v)
    di[k].append((grp[0][0], grp[-1][0]))

>>> di
{False: [(3, 9), (11, 13)], True: [(0, 2), (10, 10)]}
```

So the list `l` has a value greater than `0` in each range of `[(0, 2), (10, 10)]` and a value less than or equal to `0` in a range of `[(3, 9), (11, 13)]`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more convoluted than you would want it to be but its my 2 cents anyway:

```
l=[0.01,0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]

s = len(l) - next(i for i, x in enumerate(l[::-1]) if x != 0)
print(s)   # 11
```

Answer (score -1):

Update-> Earlier I misunderstood the question. (Thanks to dawg)

One way can be to convert the reversed list into bool array and search for first non-zero(True) value in the list.
For both operations (converting and searching) we can use built-in functions and thus better speed but it comes at cost of some memory(you haven't mentioned anything about memory consumption,so I'm assuming extra memory is available).

Here's the Code

```
bool_list = map(bool, reversed(l))
index = bool_list.index(True)

if index == -1:
    # No such sub-array found
    return len(bool_list)
else:
    # Start index of the required sub-array
    return len(bool_list) - index
```

Here, we used **reversed** instead of slice operator **[::-1]** for reversing because it is a generator function and returns element on the go without consuming any additional memory. We just need memory for bool array.

Comment: You have misunderstood what the OP is trying too do. He wants the index in l of the last run of `0` -- that has nothing to do with the number of `0` in the list.

Comment: @dawg
I'm really sorry for the inconvenience, I just misunderstood the question.
Let me Update the answer.Thank you for notifying.